# Best Policies for Low Quality Posts

Tags: discussion, support

Just reviewed a post that was flagged as low quality, indeed it was not a good post. From that observation I went to take action and got confused, and now find myself here asking this question. 
There are less options for low quality flagged posts, and if the post already has comments indicating exactly what I would have said, I'm not sure how else to be of help in that situation.
User is left with four options, none of which being "post is of low quality" or something like that.
Am I missing something?
The only option that seemed correct was perhaps edit, however I didn't have an edit to make, and again the comment I would have made was already made (aka "please provide more information that a one liner...").
I'll chalk this one up to user error, and am hoping someone(s) can point me in the right direction. Again, being user error, apologies in advance. I'm sure I'm overlooking something very obvious.